# Move replace files with in HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

With in HDFS, trying to move directory once all sub-directories/files have been processed.

Using `hadoop -mv` command through python's `subprocess` module for this.

My problem is, directories with same name can come again for processing with different set of files. `hadoop -mv` is failing with File exists error.

Looping through complete directory and move files that does not exist will make the process slow as there can be lot of sub-directories in a given directory

Is there a standard way to move files to achieve move/replace functionality?

Or can follow if there is any other standard way of handling processed files/directories

My directory structure:
New unprocessed files - /new/YEAR/MONTH/DAY/ID/files
Processed files - /processed/YEAR/MONTH/DAY/ID/files

Files will be moved to processed once all files in DAY gets processed

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what your file hierarchy looks like? I'm having a little trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to merge the contents of two directories? If you're trying to move all folders from directory a to directory to b, you can just `hdfs dfs -mv a/* b/`.

Comment: @krog, thanks for the reply. Think my problem is solved. If destination folder already exists, am using 'hadoop fs -cp' instead of -mv and delete source folder once new files are moved from source to destination. Not sure if any other better solution exists for this.  Mentioning my folder structure in question in case if you can suggest better approach

Comment: That sounds verify inefficient. Can you provide one more bit of clarification:
You said directories with the same name can come again. This means that a new `/new/Y/M/D/ID` can appear with a new set of `files`, even though `/processed/Y/M/D/ID` already exists? If you want to merge all the files together, you can do `hdfs dfs -mv /new/Y/M/D/ID/* /processed/Y/M/D/ID`, and if you want to replace the old files with the new, you can do `hdfs dfs -rm -r -f /new/Y/M/D/ID && hdfs dfs -mv /new/Y/M/D/ID /processed/Y/M/D`.

Comment: Hey krog, Sry for late reply. Processing will be done at Day level not ID level. If I do processing at ID level, hdfs commands have to be executed lot of times for moving to processed which will be consuming lot of time

Comment: It's worth mentioning that most of the time in doing an `hdfs dfs` command is spent starting up the JVM. If you do a command like `hdfs dfs -mv /a/* /b`, although it will submit multiple calls to the NameNode (one for each file matching the glob), it will be pretty fast (each call should take only a few ms).